# iPhone using NSURLConnection to get multipart data is not working right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

It seems that there is a bug in the NSURLconnection when you are getting multipart files, didReceiveResponse doesn't get called like the docs say between each part (see [this](https://devforums.apple.com/click.jspa?searchID=1138147&objectType=2&objectID=82346)).  So I think I'm going to parse all of the data that is coming in.  The format is text and binary(images) does anyone know of any code already to parse the nsdata object that is sent.  Thank You.

Comment: Ya you probably want to post your code so we can see it.

Answer (score 1):

ah, Yeah, it does. You may want to post your code or review the documentation. Perhaps your invoking NSURLConnection incorrectly.

Comment: Have you done this then, also, were there any problems getting it to work and what would you suggest I check first.  Thanks.